# How to pass argument to javascript function from grunt task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, protractor

I have getcookie(username,password) function of javascript in getcookies.js file.

```
'use strict';    
 var getcookie = function(username,password){
    //body of the getcookie method.
 };
```

I am calling this function using grunt for that I have written task in grunt.js file.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
grunt.initConfig({

pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


 protractor: {

     options: {
         keepAlive: false,
         configFile: "./config/protractorConf.js"
     },
     getcookie: {
         options: {
             args: {
                 specs: ['getcookie.js']

             }

         }
       }

      }
  });

 //Note: Create task and add it to register task. In order to run single task comment all other tasks and run
    grunt.registerTask('getcookie', ['protractor:getcookie']);
};
```

I want to pass the arguments username and password to the getcookie function from the grunt file.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Is `getcookies.js` part of a test that is run by protractor or part of your test setup?